# phpThumb IE Problem

Tags: internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7, png, phpthumb

Hi I have a theme on wordpress using phpThumb. And some images are not shown in IE7. 
It seems a problem with png transparency... What to do? Is there a parameter to pass to the script so that it will remove  transparency and show pic even with less quality, but normal?
Thanks a lot

Comment: please see on focalmag.com the third featured story with IE8.In other browsers all is OK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you will have the same issue, disable imageMagick and also in phpThumb.class.php in line

1089 find

```
 return $WriteConvert;
```

and replace with

```
return false;
```